# Determine whether one of these strings is in the line with Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm extracting data from EDICT dictionary file from wwwjdic example:

```
相同器官 [そうどうきかん] /(n) homologous organ/
相同染色体 [そうどうせんしょくたい] /(n) homologous chromosome/
相同組換え [そうどうくみかえ] /(n) homologous recombination/
相同的組み換え [そうどうてきくみかえ] /(n) homologous recombination/
相同的組換 [そうどうてきくみかえ] /(n) homologous recombination/
相同的組換え [そうどうてきくみかえ] /(n) homologous recombination/
相入れない [あいいれない] /(iK) (exp,adj-i) in conflict/incompatible/out of harmony/running counter/mutually exclusive/clashing with/
相年 [あいどし] /(n,adj-no) the same age/
相伴 [しょうばん] /(n,vs) partaking/participating/taking part in/sharing (something with someone)/
相伴う [あいともなう] /(v5u) to accompany/
相判 [あいはん] /(n,vs) (1) official seal/verification seal/affixing a seal to an official document/(2) making a joint signature or seal/
相判 [あいばん] /(n) (1) medium-sized paper (approx. 15x21 cm, used for notebooks)/(2) medium-sized photo print (approx. 10x13 cm)/
相判 [あいばん] /(n,vs) (1) official
```

The lines specify what part of speech each entry is, i.e. `/(n)` for noun and `/(adj)` for adjective. I am interested in getting all entries that are labeled for a part of speech in this array:

```
["n", "n-adv", "n-pref", "n-suf", "n-t", "num", "pn", "adj-no", "adj-f", "adv-n", "vs"]
```

I'm trying to split the lines like so

```
file = File.open("EDICT.txt")
file.each_line do |line|
   if line[#Regex]
.
.
```

I am using regex, but the furthest I got was

```
/\/[(](n|n-adv|n-pref|n-suf|n-t|num|pn|adj-no|adj-f|adv-n|vs|n,vs)[)]/
```

which is not robust. Furthermore sometimes, there are tags like this:

```
/(adj-no,n-adv,n-t)
```

that do not match the regex. At the same time it should not match these terms:

```
["adj-i", "adj-na", "adj-pn", "adj-t", "adj", "adv", "adv-to", "aux", "aux-v", "aux-adj", "conj",
"ctr", "exp", "int", "iv", "pref", "prt", "suf", "v1", "v2a-s", "v4h", "v4r", "v5", "v5argu", 
"v5b", "v5g", "v5k", "v5k-s", "v5m", "v5n", "v5r", "v5r-i", "v5s", "v5t", "v5u", "v5u-s", "v5uru",
"v5z", "vz", "vi", "vk", "vn", "vs-c", "vs-i", "vs-s", "vt"]
```

What is a better, more robust way to see if the line contains the required `/()` tags?

Answer (score -1):

```
class String
  Nouns = %w[n n-adv n-pref n-suf n-t num pn adj-no adj-f adv-n vs]
  def noun_entry?; self[%r{/\(([^)]+)\)}, 1].split(/,\s*/).&(Nouns).any? end
end

"相同器官 [そうどうきかん] /(n) homologous organ/".noun_entry?
# => true
"相判 [あいばん] /(n,vs) (1) official".noun_entry?
# => true
"ある単語 [あるたんご] /(adj-no,n-adv,n-t) .../".noun_entry?
# => true
"別の単語 [べつのたんご] /(ctr,exp,int) .../".noun_entry?
# => false
```

- `[^)]` is anything but `)`.
- `[^)]+` is a non-empty sequence that does not include `)`.
- `([^)]+)` captures such sequence.
- `%r{/\(([^)]+)\)}` is a regex that has such sequence surrounded by `/(` and `)`.
- `[regex, 1]` takes out the first capture of a match i.e., whatever that matches `[^)]+`.
- `split(/,\s*/)` separates that sequence by a comma (optionally followed by white characters) into an array.
- `&(Nouns)` takes the intersection of that array with the array `Nouns`.
- `any?` sees if anything is in the intersection.

Comment: The part I'm having hard time understanding is `([^)]+)`, self[%r{}, **1**], and `.&(Nouns)`. The `([^)]+)` uses `(..)` to match something. `[^)]` Matches anything except `)` _Why is there a plus sign?_ self[%r{}, **1**] has a second argument of 1. _What does the 1 indicate?_ You chained `&(Nouns).any?` to check if any of the split strings have something from the Nouns array. _What does `&(..)` mean?_ よろしくお願いします

Comment: For `split(/,\s*/)` It would split at / where there is zero or more occurrences of white space. This would mean it would split at both `/(n)` and `organ/`?